# How to disable autopostback on button

Tags: asp.net

I've got some dynamic created buttons in my GridView (adding them OnDataBound), but when I click some button in makes a strange PostBack and all my added button desappears... Also Click event doesn't happens.

How to :

1) Make my dynamic Button inside GridView do not disappear after clicking one of them.

2) Make this click methode works somehow ...

Im making it this way :

```
B.Click+=EventHandler(fun(_,_) : void { this.LabelCurrentCategory.Text="AAAA"; });
```

But It makes no sense... Only hides dynamic elements :(

Comment: Is your DataBinding in a !Page.IsPostBack?

Comment: Not, I do it on button ... and some more ways. Why it matters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a postback any dynamic page elements will be lost. *

Can you not stick to client-side code, and use jquery ajax to call a pagemethod on your code-behind page?

EDIT: *Unless you recreate them on the page-load.

Comment: How can I do it with jQuery and Ajax ? ... Finally I need to update single value on DataBase by clicking this button.

Comment: Sounds ideal, as you'll be passing the pagemethod the value parameter and not needing to interact with other controls on the page from your code-behind.  Start by looking here; http://weblogs.asp.net/craigshoemaker/archive/2008/09/29/using-jquery-to-call-asp-net-ajax-page-methods.aspx

Comment: takes a bit of fiddling the first time, but it's pretty cool once you get it working and tie it in with the jquery effects.

Comment: Yes ... I still on thinking on it ... It's hard tutorials and this things confusing me and just "doen't works" again and again. I Can not find tutorials "For Blondes" >_<